# PHP Sort Array By Element ASC and then by key ASC for same values

Tags: php

First of all i didnt find similar topic in stackoverflow although there is something from another user but the solution there didnt work for me (ASC/DESC).

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [4] => 60
    [3] => 80
    [5] => 20
    [2] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [6] => 30
)
```

The result must be the following:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0 
    [5] => 20
    [6] => 30
    [4] => 60
    [3] => 80
)
```

I just tryed to do and become confused.

**

### EDIT

**

asort() Doesnt work on this array

```
$array = array(
    4 => 60,
    3 => 80,
    5 => 20,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    6 => 30
);
```

The result of asort is:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [5] => 20
    [6] => 30
    [4] => 60
    [3] => 80
)
```

**Which is wrong, since the key 2 must be after the key 1**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Slightly more complicated...

```
$array = array(
    4 => 60,
    3 => 80,
    5 => 20,
    2 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    6 => 30
);

$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
array_multisort($values, SORT_ASC, $keys, SORT_ASC);
$array = array_combine($keys, $values);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: It's wrong. Doesn't work.

Try to do asort on this array. It will swap the array index
$arrTags[1] = 0;
$arrTags[2] = 0;

Comment: haha. ok well asort does exactly what you asked. I'm looking at the result right now! I'll post the whole code...

Comment: Yes try the first example in my comments here. The arr[1] and arr[2] are being changed with asort but the returned array should be the same as input

Answer (score 1):

Try to reverse sort and then sort:

```
   $array = array(
    4 => 60,
    3 => 80,
    5 => 20,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    6 => 30
);
arsort($array);
asort($array);
print_r($array);
```